# Hive Text to ORC conversion using Java

Tags: java, orc

I want to know if I can convert a Text file to ORC file to be used in Hive using a java solution.

We dont want to use a hive query to convert it. Any suggestions?

Comment: What are you using currently?

Comment: Barring Hive, you can still use Pig, Spark... or any framework that can access the ORC Serde and interact with the Hive MetaStore (via HCatalog API).

Comment: My Question was conversion of text to orc .... using Java

Answer (score 0):

To write an ORC file, you need to define the schema and create a Writer with the desired filename. This example sets the required schema parameter, but there are many other options to control the ORC writer.

```
TypeDescription schema = TypeDescription.fromString("struct<x:int,y:int>");
Writer writer = OrcFile.createWriter(new Path("my-file.orc"),
              OrcFile.writerOptions(conf)
                     .schema(schema));
```

Now you need to create a row batch, set the data, and write it to the file as the batch fills up. When the file is done, close the Writer.

```
VectorizedRowBatch batch = schema.createRowBatch();
LongColumnVector x = (LongColumnVector) batch.cols[0];
LongColumnVector y = (LongColumnVector) batch.cols[1];
for(int r=0; r < 10000; ++r) {
    int row = batch.size++;
    x.vector[row] = r;
    y.vector[row] = r * 3;
    // If the batch is full, write it out and start over.
    if (batch.size == batch.getMaxSize()) {
        writer.addRowBatch(batch);
        batch.reset();
    }
}
writer.close();
```

More details on ORC web site: https://orc.apache.org/docs/core-java.html#writing-orc-files